# Finite automaton for all words whose length $n$ satisfies $\operatorname{gcd}(n,504) \geq 6$

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

I have been working on the following homework question, and I just can't seem to make any progress:

> Construct a finite automaton having fewer than 36 states that recognizes the language $\{s \in a^* : \operatorname{gcd}(|s|, 504) \geq 6\}$, where $|s|$ is the length of $s$.

So far I have been trying to figure out a regular pattern in $504$ and have broken it down to the prime factorization $504 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$, which means that all divisors must be multiples of 2, 3, or 7. However I don't know how to create the finite automaton (NFA or DFA). Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The number $504$ has $4\cdot3\cdot2=24$ divisors:
$$1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 12,
 14,
 18,
 21,
 24,
 28,
 36,
 42,
 56,
 63,
 72,
 84,
 126,
 168,
 252,
 504$$
Out of these, $20$ are at least $6$:
$$
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 12,
 14,
 18,
 21,
 24,
 28,
 36,
 42,
 56,
 63,
 72,
 84,
 126,
 168,
 252,
 504$$
For an integer $n$, $\operatorname{gcd}(n,504) \geq 6$ iff $n$ is a multiple of one of these numbers. To check this, we don't really need to go over all $20$ possibilities. For example, if $n$ is divisible by $12$ then it is also divisible by $6$, so we can remove $12$ from the list. The list narrows down to only $4$ options:
$$
6,7,8,9
$$
That is,
$$
\operatorname{gcd}(n,504) \geq 6 \Leftrightarrow 6 \mid n \text{ or } 7 \mid n \text{ or } 8 \mid n \text{ or } 9 \mid n
$$
You can check the condition on the right using an NFA with $6+7+8+9 = 30$ states (or $31$ states if you do not allow multiple initial states).

Comment: Thanks Yuval that makes sense. So would this NFA just be showing numbers divisble by 6,7,8,9?

Comment: That’s what my answer seems to imply.

Comment: Note that `\gcd` is already predefined in LaTeX (and MathJax); you don’t have to write it with `\operatorname`.